# javascript how to run functions with 'when' and 'then'

Tags: javascript, jquery, .when

I have searched stack already for questions like this and cannot find a clear answer.  I have a fiddle that types out a letter by letter from a word. But when I run the function twice, it does it together.  I tried using when and then but it still doesn't seem to work. I expect the outcome to be "Hello, World! Hello2" but instead it prints it together, "HHeelllloo...."

http://jsfiddle.net/Jsbbvk/vL8tLwfh/

(some pseudo-code)

```
$.when(showText(param1, param2)).then(function() {
  showText(param3, param4);
});
```

Comment: what does `showText(param1, param2)` do? and return - oh, I see, it returns undefined ... do you know what `$.when` does?

Comment: `$.when` can do no magic (and it shouldn't be used here at all). Your `showText` function needs to return a promise that will get resolved when the animation is done.

Comment: what's your expected result?

Comment: Do you know how callbacks work? If not, start with that. Use one as the parameter to `showText`, and call it in the `else` part of `if (index < message.length)` - i.e. when the iteration ended

Comment: Thanks Bergi, I have looked into this and made a sucessful showText function with a callback!

Comment: Great! You might want to [post it as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I try to explain why it happen :

- Firstly $.when(showText(params)) called then It append the first
  index ("H") to "div"
- Then function of setTimeout called with interval, which showText is
  called again
- But the your $.when(showText(params)) not wait until setTimeout is
  finished,
- So, $then method called and run your showText("#msg", "Hello2", 0,
  500) while showText("#msg", "Hello, World!", 0, 500) is still running
  after print "H"
- So both of them running in the same time, not wait each other

I try to fix your code instead of using $.when and $.the, I am using callback function. So callback doesn't call before setInterval finish it job.

```js
function showText (target, message, index, interval, callback) {
  if (index < message.length) { 
    $(target).append(message[index++]); 
    var session = setTimeout(function () {
     showText(target, message, index, interval, callback);
      if(index === message.length -1){
       callback ? callback() : null;
      }
    }, interval); 
  }
}
    
$(function () { 

    showText("#msg", "Hello, World!", 0, 500, function(){
     showText("#msg", "Hello2", 0, 500)
    })
    
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="msg"/> 
<span id="text_target"></span>
```

my fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/firhatsungkar/zg9un4po/